# My home box as my own host?

Tags: web-development, hosting

I have a 512 kb/s DSL service at home. I do not have a static IP but I can get one if I pay some extra to my ISP.

Now, if I get the static IP, can I make my home box act as my internet host? What else do I need?

P.S. I know that if at all possible, the site I make available this way might be slow, that is alright, my question is if it is possible at all.

Edit:
I need this for very small traffic. I am a PHP developer and for my projects I am often asked to provide a demo. I currently use a free hosting for this purpose but it is down most of the time and support is non-existent. So I thought to set-up my home computer as my test server.

With this please note that:

1. I will only occasionally have 'visitors' and that will be one or possibly two visitors at any time.
2. These demos, are to showcase functionality, so no big images are served and page views will normally generate under 100KB of traffic.

Comment: Just because your ISP will sell you a static IP doesn't mean they allow servers on their network.  Check your terms of service / acceptable use policy.  It's also possible that they'll have some ports open by default, but block others (eg, SMTP, so you don't turn into an open relay)

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/66947/how-to-host-website-from-my-home-adsl or http://serverfault.com/questions/4658/what-are-some-pitfalls-of-hosting-a-website-from-home or http://serverfault.com/questions/127478/hosting-multiple-websites-from-home or http://serverfault.com/questions/111614/is-it-possible-to-view-my-apache-server-local-host-from-home-or-remote-computer or http://serverfault.com/questions/27547/problem-hosting-server-behing-personal-router or http://serverfault.com/questions/108232/website-hosting-from-home-iis6

Comment: or http://serverfault.com/questions/36457/server-hosting-from-your-house-200-to-300-per-month-range or http://serverfault.com/questions/128757/hosting-a-server-for-websites-ftp-and-random-use-at-home or http://serverfault.com/questions/116643/can-i-have-web-server-on-a-home-network-with-1-public-ip-address or http://serverfault.com/questions/70532/opinions-on-hosting-servers-in-house - the list goes on

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. What is wrong with this question?

Comment: It's downvoted because it's been asked so many times as Farseeker has laboriously pointed out.

Comment: @ Joe: My ISP does not prohibit that. At least I didn't find anything related in their terms of service.

Comment: @Farseeker: Thank you for the links. They're very informative.

Comment: @Farseeker, our own human Rolodex. You are human, right? Or are you Evan's twin? Which one is the evil one? Do you bleed milk?

Comment: @Wesley, Google is your friend: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Aserverfault.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a - and if I were evans twin I would be > 10k rep - it seems to be an illusive target

Comment: If you are charging people for your work, there is no reason why you can't afford some bargain basement PHP hosting. dreamhost.com, hawkhost.com, you can get hosting plans that cost in the order of $50 or less a year. If you want to be taken seriously as a professional, you need to invest in stuff like this.

Comment: Hawkhost "Basic" shared hosting (should be plenty) ~US$40/year
http://www.hawkhost.com/Shared/compare
Coupons are regularly available for 50% off 
http://www.retailmenot.com/view/hawkhost.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static ip address is not a neccessity. You can host your own email\web\ftp\etc server with a dynamic ip address in conjunction with a dynamic DNS service, such as [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.com/).

Comment: This is very good news. Seems I have all needed to start immediately.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what you want to host.  A web site?  Email?  A high-performance compute cloud?

If it's just a simple web site, yes, then you can install some flavor of Linux (or you can use Windows, somehow a quick Ubuntu LAMP install seems about right in this case) including Apache as a web server.

You'd need to choose and register a domain name and - probably through the registrar - arrange for a DNS entry for the name to point to your static IP.

And Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Thanks Ward, your answer assured me there are no unknown bits I miss (though I hadn't thought about the domain name registration and dns)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to do this, but it might be more trouble than it's worth.  If you just want to host a web site, you can get a deal from one of the big web hosting providers such as Dreamhost, GoDaddy or FatCow that will probably cost about the same as paying your ISP the extra money for a fixed IP address.

Comment: I explained my use for it in an edit in my question. I guess everybody agrees with such low usage hosting from home is the obvious option.